# How can I deploy Ultralytics YOLOv8 on Microsoft Azure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, pytorch, yolov8

There are very simple quickstart guides on how to deploy Ultralytics YOLOv8 on GCP and AWS:

- Google Cloud Deep Learning VM: https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/wiki/GCP-Quickstart
- Amazon Deep Learning AMI: https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/wiki/AWS-Quickstart

Is there a similar way to deploy YOLOv8 on Microsoft Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft currently has no official docs about YOLO v8 but you can surely use it in Azure environment you can use this documentations([1](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5))([2](https://github.com/balakreshnan/Samples2023/blob/main/AzureML/yolov8.md)) as guidance.